# Using the same login in two projects with ASP.NET MVC5 Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to share the same login cookie to two differents MVC5 projects.

I've already set the same cookie name to both projects, but thats doesnt work.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = "OrienteIntegrada",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Permite que o aplicativo valide o carimbo de segurança quando o usuário efetuar login.
                // Este é um recurso de segurança que é usado quando você altera uma senha ou adiciona um login externo à sua conta.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Both apps are in the same site... and I can get them by accessing localhost/teste and localhost/teste2;

Am I supposed to set anything in IIS?
I'm sorry about my english... I hope you may understand me. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same `machinekey` for the both applications and they will share the secure data. Here is how you can add `machinekey` to the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryptionKey="F6722806843145965513817CEBDECBB1F94808E4A6C0B2F2,IsolateApps" validationKey="C551753B0325187D1759B4FB055B44F7C5077B016C02AF674E8DE69351B69FEFD045A267308AA2DAB81B69919402D7886A6E986473EEEC9556A9003357F5ED45,IsolateApps" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Do not use the above values on production. Only use on your test applications.

You can generate machine key following the instructions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vijaysk/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager

Comment: @GustavoBorges Glad that it helped. Hope you do not mind marking the answer as the accepted one (the tick sign under the vote icon)?